# get complete value in a string regex

Tags: php, regex

i have string like this

```
$data = ":lol :D :| :( :cool :shy :) :P :h :search :'( :cry :think :y :@ :xd :punch :* :angle :sick :flower"
```

you can see string value is seprate with a space

```
$requested = ":lo";
 if (preg_match_all("/$requested/", $data, $matches)) { ?>

            <p><?php print_r($matches); ?></p>
<?php }
```

i want regex to return complete value till space
my mean if $requested value be :lo it return :lol
what should i do thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may append `\S*` pattern that matches 0 or more non-whitespace symbols (greedily, as many as possible, as the `*` is a greedy quantifier) to the regex:

```
$data = ":lol :D :| :( :cool :shy :) :P :h :search :'( :cry :think :y :@ :xd :punch :* :angle :sick :flower";
$requested = ":lo";
if (preg_match_all("~" . preg_quote($requested, "~") . "\S*~", $data, $matches)) {
  print_r($matches[0]);
}
// => :lol
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/Aj83Ir)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `\S*`. This will search for `:lo` plus any amount non-whitespace characters.

```
$data = ":lol :D :| :( :cool :shy :) :P :h :search :'( :cry :think :y :@ :xd :punch :* :angle :sick :flower";
$requested = ":lo";
if (preg_match_all("/($requested)\S*/", $data, $matches)) { ?>
            <p><?php print_r($matches); ?></p>
<?php }
```

Note that the regex could break if `$requested` contains a variety of special characters (`/\()[].*+` etc). You can use [preg_quote()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) to fix this.

```
$requested = ":lo"
$requested = preg_quote($requested, '/');
```